# How do you split a word in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want such an output such that when the input is a string "HARSHA", then it must be split into the constituent alphabets and they should get printed on separate lines.

Comment: use String.toCharArray() and then print each element of array in separate line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split() method in the class java.lang.String

```
String word = "ahmet enes";
String[] alphabets = word.split("");
for(String alphabet : alphabets)
    {
    System.out.println(alphabet);
    }
```

Thanks to @Pshemo to remind me it may not work on previous versions

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this will work only since Java 8. In Java 7 and earlier we would get array starting with empty string like `"abc".split("")->["","a","b","c"]`.